# Working with list of objects in net core MVC

Tags: c#, database, list, linq

I have a some questions about utilizing lists in models.

In short:
I have model User which inherits from IdentityUser. There is some extra fields and a list of objects(lets say list of childs) so

`public List<Child> Childs`

Now i don't know how lists are stored in database, are they tho?
There is no column Childs. Is it used only to store data taken from DB?

My problem is that i don't know how to work with it. Lets say i want to display all childs from logged user. Do i loop through all childs, find which have users id, move it to list and then foreach loop it? Or i should access directly Childs list without taking data from DB first?
But then what happens if i change data of some childs?
Lets say i added 2 childs to 1 user, later change data of single child, that way data of this child won't change in list and i need to change it in every list? I believe that's not how it's handled.

Hope i can get some explanations on lists.

Comment: You're asking more than one question here. I suggest you simplify your question.

Comment: To find items in your list use the Where clause in "Language-Integrated Query (LINQ)."

Comment: @TroyTurley So i go like taking data from Childs table and use LINQ to display data? Then what's the point of using lists in model if i can filter data by LINQ. Or as i said this list is only to store data filtered by LINQ

Comment: LINQ is a set of methods that can act on List<T>. You need both the List and LINQ. If you use LINQ you don't have to loop through the List to find items.

Comment: You are mixing up too many things. A model is only used to represent the data. It has nothing to do with displaying. And, to the best of my knowledge, there is no way to fill a model with List<> directly from a database in one query. You will need to write your own code to fill the list. i.e. List<int> children = new(); then populate your list. Then mymodel.childs = children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I don't know how lists are stored in database, are they tho? There is no column Childs. Is it used only to store data taken from DB?

Usually records are sored in separate table, for example `UserChild`, which has reference to parent table

> Lets say I want to display all `Childs` from logged user.

```cs
var allChildren = ctx.Users
   .Where(u => u.Id == userId)
   .SelectMany(u => u.Childs)
   .ToList();
```

> But then what happens if I change data of some childs? Lets say I added 2 childs to 1 user, later change data of single child, that way data of this child won't change in list and i need to change it in every list? I believe that's not how it's handled.

Changes should be recorded in appropriate table and query above should get updated data from Database.

Probably before starting doing something, you should read EF Core documentation.